# how can we format data like this pickle

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to use [PyUpset](https://github.com/ImSoErgodic/py-upset) package and it has test data in  pickel which can be found [here](https://github.com/ImSoErgodic/py-upset/tree/master/src/data)

I can ran the following code to view content and format of data

```
from pickle import load
with open('./test_data_dict.pckl', 'rb') as f:
   data_dict = load(f)
data_dict
```

which showed data to be of following format, it just an example how it looks like,

```
   [495 rows X 4 columns],
    'adventure':          title rating_avg \
        0                20,000 Leagues Under the Sea (1954)    3.702609    
        1                 7th Voyage of Sinbad, The (1958)      3.616279

             rating_std views
        0     0.869685    575  
        1     0.931531    258  

     [281 rows x 4 columns],
    'romance':          title rating_avg \
        0                'Til There Was You (1997)    2.402609    
        1                 1-900 (1994)                2.411279

             rating_std views
        0     0.669685    575  
        1     0.981310    245
```

I have been trying to format my csv data in this way and the closest I was able to get was using pandas to something like this

csv file in the following format,

```
Type_A, Type_B, Type_C
x1,x2,x3
y1,y2,y3
```

used pandas to import in dataframe and concat them together after adding an index

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv(csv_file)
d1=df.Type_A.tolist()
d2=df.Type_B.tolist()
d3=df.Type_C.tolist()
```

then to add index used enumerate ()

```
d1_df=list(enumerate(d1, 1))
d2_df=list(enumerate(d2, 1))
d3_df=list(enumerate(d3, 1))
d1_df  # this gives me [(1, 'x1'), (2, 'y1')]
```

Now next I added lables Id and Value to dataframe

```
labels = ['Id','Value']
d1_df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(d1_df, columns=labels)
d2_df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(d2_df, columns=labels)
d3_df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(d3_df, columns=labels)


d1_df  # this gives me Id Value
       #            0   1    x1
       #            1   2    y1
```

then combined all 3 into one dataframe and redefine Type_A , Type_B and Type_C

```
child_df = [d1_df, d2_df, d3_df]
labels2 = ['Type_A','Type_B','Type_C']

parent_df = pd.concat(child_df, keys=['Type_A', 'Type_B', 'Type_C'])

parent_df # out below


#          Id Value
#Type_A 0   1    x1
#       1   2    y1
#Type_B 0   1    x2
#       1   2    y2
#Type_C 0   1    x3
#       1   2    y3
```

This is where I am struck, I think I am using wrong approach and it should be simpler to get data in the format how PyUpset used.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to transpose the table so that it is in 'long' format. Once you do that you can use the groupby method in pandas to make the correct dictionary for pyupset.

```
import pandas as pd
try:
    # for Python 2.x
    from StringIO import StringIO
except ImportError:
    # for Python 3.x
    from io import StringIO

test_string = StringIO("""Type_A,Type_B,Type_C
x1,x2,x3
y1,y2,y3""")

df = pd.read_csv(test_string)
df = pd.melt(df, var_name='type')
# df now looks like this:
#
#    type      value
# 0  Type_A    x1
# 1  Type_A    y1
# 2  Type_B    x2
# 3  Type_B    y2
# 4  Type_C    x3
# 5  Type_C    y3

pyupset_data = {key: df.loc[value] for key, value in df.groupby("type").groups.items()}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's actually just a plain python dict with values as entire dataframes.  The key is the title you want along the bottom row.